# Distinction between a/b versions of Matlab?

Tags: version, matlab, versioning

So I am relatively new to Matlab and was wondering what the distinction is between the a and b versions of Matlab in the past few years? Are the "b" versions incremental updates? Or the same software with additional features? What about the latest releases 2010a and 2010b?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MathWorks has been putting out two releases of MATLAB per year for the past few years. The first one early in the year is *a* and the second one later on is *b*. The *b* release is a new version of MATLAB, not an incremental update.

They started this versioning scheme in 2006 and still maintain a numerical version number in the background. Here's a [release history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB#Release_history).